# ¿Qué quiere decir "de a poco"?

Tags: hispanoamérica, locuciones

Estaba escuchando [un vídeo de una conferencia](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FI_8bKiW8wg) de una científica de Chile cuando oí la frase:

> (...) lo que yo esperaba era ir construyendo productos, porque me interesaba analizar datos, **de a poco** y eso no lo encontraba.
>
> <sub>3:35 del vídeo [Riva Quiroga: "Aprender a programar con un enfoque comunicativo" | Starsconf 2018](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FI_8bKiW8wg) en YouTube</sub>

El DAMER explica:

> [**poco**](http://lema.rae.es/damer/?key=poco)
>
> c. ǁ    **de a ~**.
>   i.  loc. adv. Cu, Ec, Pe, Bo, Ch, Py, Ar, Ur. Lentamente, despacio. pop. (de a pocos).
>   ii. Gu, Ni, Cu, Bo, Ch. En pequeñas porciones o cantidades de algo. pop.
>
> d. **de a ~s**. loc. adv. Pe. de a poco, lentamente.

Entonces: ¿quiere decir exactamente lo mismo que "poco a poco"? ¿Se usa solamente en contexto coloquial? ¿Realmente en Perú se usa igual pero diciendo *de a poco**s*** (plural) en lugar de *de a poco*?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Efectivamente

> de a poco

es una forma tanto coloquial como académica y quiere decir exactamente lo mismo que

> poco a poco

Aquí hay una referencia sobre su uso en Chile del diccionario [Dictionary of Chilean Slang: Your Key to Chilean Language and Culture](https://books.google.com.ar/books?id=UwVYtrmBIEYC&pg=PT204&dq=%22de+a+poco%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiczIXT5qjmAhUDK7kGHQUQAqQQ6AEIKDAA#v=onepage&q=%22de%20a%20poco%22&f=false) (que coincide exactamente con el empleo en Argentina)

> **de a poco** (lentamente; concuidado; escrupulosamente; cf. uno a uno, paso a paso, avanzar con pie de plomo, despacito por las piedras, piano piano poco a poco, ir de a poco; "Beto, tienes que comenzar de a poco con la mina; primero llámala por teléfono para saber cómo está, después ayúdala con sus proyectos de diseño y llévale unas flores a su madre, después invítala al cine, y si las cosas se van dando, ya pueden salir a bailar por ahí", "de a poco, conciudadanos, hemos ido venciendo la pobreza en Chile...", "de a poco los políticos nos van robando el presupuesto y los bienes nacionales hasta que comienza todo de nuevo el año siguiente")
>
> [image]

Y esta es una forma de la expresión escrita en un [texto](https://books.google.com.ar/books?id=jnTHWUhHQCIC&pg=PT89&dq=%22de+a+poco%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiXsJrv5qjmAhWQF7kGHa-PA1U4FBDrAQh1MAg#v=onepage&q=%22de%20a%20poco%22&f=false) sobre Ernesto Guevara (el Che, nacido en Córdoba, Argentina)

> Ernesto Guevara, el hombre que llegaría a ser el Che, empezó a crecer en Alta Gracia, un pueblo remolón y tranquilo a las puertas del valle de Paravachasca, cuarenta kilómetros al suroeste de la ciudad de Córdoba. Allí tuvo sus primeros amigos, hizo sus primeras lecturas y empezó a asomarse **de a poco** a una vida que con los años sería intensa, feroz y mítica.
>
> [image: texto sobre el Che Guevara]

Comment: ¿Es académica también? El DAMER no lo indicaba.